# JSON Transform Task in Build Definition in VSTS

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am using VSTS for CI/CD process in my project.

As of now, we have few config files in project with `*.deployment.config` extension. We are using `XDT Transform` task in build definition which applies transform to  all files having extension `*.deployment.config`.

Similarly, I am looking for a task to transform my json files. I want to keep `*.deployment.json` files and want them to be transformed into `.json` file on build.

I also got one task, mentioned below. But this will transform only one file at a time. Hence, we will have to create multiple tasks for multiple json files.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sergeyzwezdin.magic-chunks

Could anyone please suggest a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No built-in tasks/extensions can transform multiple json files, there is a related extension: [File Patch Build and Release Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-file-patch).

On the other hand, you can build a custom task through VSTS extension: [Add a build or release task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=vsts)

Answer (score 2):

There is now a built-in Azure DevOps Services Task to perform this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops

Comment: That's cool, but I'm having the same issue as described [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/552873/file-transform-task-missing-form-azure-devops-serv.html). Where can I find this extension so that it can be installed on our server?

Comment: According to the current docs, this should now be out of preview and available for Azure Devops Server 2019.  I don't have a local server install, so I can't verify.

Comment: no, this does not work with JSON, it supports only XML files.